# Hide vertical scrollbar without usage of outer / inner containers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to get rid of vertical scroll bar for one of the elements on my page yet, keep it scrollable. I am aware of solutions that use outer / inner containers and overflow techniques to push scroll bar of into invisible areas, but would like to achieve this without any additional elements. So far I have tried following approach:

```
.element {
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.element {
    display: none;
}
```

However after some research I discovered that `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;` is depreciated and no longer works in firefox, this is where I need help. Maybe some sort of jQuery alternative to fix the issue in firefox?

Comment: Could you provide more information, such as your HTML code? For example tables do different things than divs etc... More context would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a custom scrollbar. [Scrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) has lots of options and seems to be one of the most popular ones. Combining it with the [mousewheel](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js) and set `display: none !importnant;` to the scroll bar and the scroll track will visually give you what you need